# How to get org.neo4j.graphdb.Node from a SDN NodeEntity?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is there a way to get the *org.neo4j.graphdb.Node* object that corresponds to the Spring Data Neo4j NodeEntity object?

My current workaround is to use the NodeEntity graphId value to load the *org.neo4j.graphdb.Node* object but i want to avoid loading the node again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template.getPersistentState(entity)` -> Node or Rel

Comment: Is this also in someway possible when using SDN 4.0.0.M1?